# UPDATE table SET column=DEFAULT not working

Tags: sqlite

What is the correct way to `UPDATE` a column to the `DEFAULT` value?
The documentation suggests that it can be used only in `INSERT` statements.

```
drop table if exists testjulian;
create table testjulian( 
jul REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT ( julianday('now'))
,whatever STRING);

insert into testJulian values(null,"a"); --null not allowed
insert into testJulian(whatever) values("b"); --default value is used

update testjulian set jul= DEFAULT ; --syntax error
update testjulian set jul= NULL ; --null not allowed
```

Comment: Default values in SQL generally have to do with the default value to be used during an _insert_, not during an update.  So, you will have to just specify the values you want to use in the update explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DEFAULT keyword is limited to being used when creating a table and it is designed for when inserting.

It cannot be used for an update, hence the syntax error.

In your case you could use :-

```
update testjulian set jul = julianday('now');
```

Or if you really wanted to dynamically get the DEFAULT value you could extract it from the **sql** column of sqlite_master.

e.g. using

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'testjulian';
```

gives you :-

> CREATE TABLE testjulian(jul REAL NOT NULL **DEFAULT (
>   julianday('now'))**,whatever STRING)